# Hibernate session in HandlerInterceptor

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

i'm  writing this post for this resean.
I have a couple model with get method annotated to lazy init
Everithing is ok in the controller context, if I do

```
Hibernate.initialize(p.getDentist());
```

The relation will be loaded correctly
But the same things not work in the handlerinterceptor preHandle method (HandlerInterceptorAdapter). In this context i got the exception below

```
[c.t.c.j.s.h.MappingExceptionResolver.logException] - Unexpected exception: could not initialize proxy - no Session org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
```

I'm really not understand why. I mean, maybe the context is different and the prehandle method is called before the hibernate session was iniziatized.
Any suggestions?

Many thanks to all

I use this spring version 4.3.4.RELEASE.
spring data 1.10.4.RELEASE
hibernate version 4.2.21.Final